# how to export data to csv file in specific order

Tags: python, scrapy

I find several solutions on how to extract data in a specific order by overriding class `OrderItem`

```
class OrderedItem(scrapy.Item):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._values = OrderedDict()
        if args or kwargs:
            for k, v in six.iteritems(dict(*args, **kwargs)):
                self[k] = v
```

I have more data that is being extracted and every time the order is different
        def **repr**(self):
            return json.dumps(OrderedDict(self), ensure_ascii = False)

```
class NewItem(OrderedItem):
    title = scrapy.Field()
    price = scrapy.Field()
```

Then inside crawler script, i defined an instance of `NewItem` object

```
def parse(self, response):
        items = NewItem()
        items['title'] = response.xpath(
"//span[@class='pdp-mod-product-badge-title'/text()").extract_first()
        items['price'] = response.xpath("//span[contains(@class, 'pdp-price')]/text()").extract_first()

        yield items
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to define your order in `settings.py`:

```
FEED_EXPORT_FIELDS = ["title", "price"]
```